# Add NSString to NSMutableArray crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, ipad, nsmutablearray

On my iOS app, I have a UI with two things : a picker view and a button.

I initialize my picker view with a NSMutableArray like this :

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *_pickerDataCategory;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   // Initialize Data
    _pickerDataCategory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray  *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                            @"cat1", @"cat2", @"cat3", @"cat4", nil ];

    _pickerDataCategory = array;

 //First I had initialize like this :  NSMutableArray  *_pickerDataCategory = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                            @"cat1", @"cat2", @"cat3", @"cat4", nil ];
}
```

Then I have a button which display a pop up where the user can write something. The aim of this method is to **add a new NSString object to my NSMutableArray**.

```
   - (IBAction)addNewCategory:(id)sender {
        __block bool isNotExist = false;
           UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @"Add new category"
                                                                                  message: @"Please write a new category"
                                                                           preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
            textField.placeholder = @"Category";
            textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        }];
    UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];

    UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        NSString *input = alertController.textFields[0].text;
        //Check if the category exist already

        for (NSString *category in _pickerDataCategory)
        {
            if ([category isEqualToString:input])
            {
                 [self popupMessage:@"Category already exists" title:@"Error"];
                isNotExist = false;
                return;
            }else{
                NSString *msg = [@"Category has been added : " stringByAppendingString:input];
                 [self popupMessage:msg title:@"Ok"];
                isNotExist = true;


                //[_pickerDataCategory addObject:input];//CRASH
              //  [_picker_cateogry reloadAllComponents];

            }
        }



    }];

    [alertController addAction:cancel];
    [alertController addAction:ok];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

But It crashed when I want to add the Textfield input to my NSMutableArray. I really don't understand why. I was careful about the initialization of my NSMutableArray. I looked for any information on the internet about it and the two informations I found was either about the initialization or either if it's a mutable array and not a simple array.

Moreover, I don't understand why if I add some code after `[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];` , it is not executed... I did not find any information as well about it.

Could you please help me to figure out why It crashed and It's not working ?
Thank

Comment: Could you please add the crash message you got too? Would make finding the problem a bit more easier! :)

Comment: @rikh , Yes forgot. I just edit my post ;) thank !

Comment: Put a breakpoint where you are trying to `addObject` to the array and check if the value is `nil`?

Comment: Actually, even If I write [_pickerDataCategory addObject:@"Test"], it crashed...So I don't think this is the value is nil.

Comment: No It's not. I just checked it. If it's nil it display an error message and I did not get anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as your crash, it's probably related to you trying to modify the array while you're enumerating it.  I would break these up into two separate tasks.

Something like...

```
NSMutableArray *additionalObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *category in _pickerDataCategory) {
    if (![category isEqualToString:input]) {
        [additionalObjects addObject: category];
    }
}

[_pickerDataCategory addObjectsFromArray: additionalObjects];
```

Comment: Thank ! I just tried by doing it in two tasks like you said. Once the user has written something, the NSString is stored, and then after the loop, I add it to the NSMutableArray. 
And do you know why, if I put some code after the presentViewController, It's not executed ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to add values to your array while iterating , save your data on other array and then add it to your     _pickerDataCategory

Comment: nice observation Marat

Answer (score 3):

The code will be like this:- while enumerating

```
    - (IBAction)addNewCategory:(id)sender {
    __block bool isNotExist = false;
       UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @"Add new category"
                                                                              message: @"Please write a new category"
                                                                       preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Category";
        textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    }];
UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];

UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    NSString *input = alertController.textFields[0].text;
    //Check if the category exist already
    NSMutableArray * arrTemp = _pickerDataCategory;
    for (NSString *category in arrTemp)
    {
        if ([category isEqualToString:input])
        {
             [self popupMessage:@"Category already exists" title:@"Error"];
            isNotExist = false;
            return;
        }else{
            NSString *msg = [@"Category has been added : " stringByAppendingString:input];
             [self popupMessage:msg title:@"Ok"];
            isNotExist = true;


            [_pickerDataCategory addObject:input];//CRASH
            [_picker_cateogry reloadAllComponents];

        }
    }



}];

[alertController addAction:cancel];
[alertController addAction:ok];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

  }
```

Comment: just have to replace your enumerating array as temp